# How to destroy one radix tree in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, radix-tree

I'm trying to use radix tree to maintain one internal data for the driver. So what's the proper way to destroy the whole tree?

One thought is to traverse the tree with the method mentioned at: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848182/)

For each node, free the item and delete its key from the tree.

The other question is, is `radix_tree_for_each_slot()` safe with delete item inside the loop? Will delete trigger internal shrink and cause iteration failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [cgwb_bdi_unregister](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/backing-dev.c#L701).

It seems to be doing pretty much what you need - it iterates over the radix tree with `radix_tree_for_each_slot()` and while doing so it does also `radix_tree_delete` (from [cgwb_kill](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/backing-dev.c#L519)).

So I guess nothing should blow up if you're keeping things properly synchronized.

Comment: How about radix tree itself? Or say, is radix_tree_delete the only operation to destroy the tree?

Comment: OK, originally I was worry about radix_tree_node_cachep created by kmem_cache_create.  It seems there is only one cahcep created at init time, and all trees share the same one, then no need and should not destroy it. Thanks!

Comment: For those who can't find it: `cgwb_bdi_destroy` has been renamed to `cgwb_bdi_unregister`.